# wcf сервис, передача больших файлов

Tags: wcf, tcp, upload, pipes

Есть служба WCF

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WCF
{
public class ServerService : IServerService
{
    public ServerService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server init");
    }

    public void UploadFiles(Dictionary<string, byte[]> files)
    {
        string pathToUploadFolder = @"C:\Upload";
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(pathToUploadFolder + "\\" + file.Key, file.Value);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Для её хостинга используется консольное приложение. 
App.Config Сервера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
      <service name="WCF.ServerService" behaviorConfiguration="ServerServiceMEXBehavior">
       <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF.IServerService" />
       <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WCF.IServerService"/>
       <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="WCF.IServerService" />

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8008/UploadService"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhsot:8009/UploadService"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/UploadService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServerServiceMEXBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Написан простейший клиент к этой службе:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Client.ServiceReference1;
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServerServiceClient client = new ServerServiceClient("NetNamedPipeBinding_IServerService"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Send file");
                string name = "test.rar";
                var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Pol\Desktop\test.rar");
                Dictionary<string, byte[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
                dictionary.Add(name, fileBytes);
                client.UploadFiles(dictionary);
                Console.WriteLine("End");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.Config клиента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServerService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netNamedPipeBinding>
                <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IServerService" />
            </netNamedPipeBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IServerService" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8008/UploadService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServerService" contract="ServiceReference1.IServerService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IServerService" />
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhsot:8009/UploadService" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IServerService" contract="ServiceReference1.IServerService"
            name="NetTcpBinding_IServerService">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="Pol-PC\Pol" />
            </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/UploadService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IServerService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IServerService" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IServerService">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="Pol-PC\Pol" />
            </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Хотелось бы узнать, как необходимо изменить конфигурацию, чтобы было возможно отправлять файлы объёмом ~2Gb через tcp соединение и именованные каналы

Answer (score 3):

С моей точки зрения - только включив [WCF Streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx). Либо реализовывать что-то подобное самостоятельно, иначе WCF будет пытаться весь файл в 2 Гб держать в памяти чтобы создать сообщение для отсылки.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически, можно настроить параметры `maxReceivedMessageSize` и `maxReceivedMessageSize` примерно таким образом

```
<binding maxBufferSize="64000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="64000000" />
```

Максимальное значение по документации должно допускать до [Int64.Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.100).aspx), но по отзывам - только до [Int32.Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004717/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-maxreceivedmessagesize-can-be-set-to-for-a-netname). Если справедливо первое - у вас заведомо достаточно для передачи 2 Гб, второе - немногим менее 2 Гб.

Тем не менее, соглашусь со мнением выше, что лучше в такой ситуации, в соответствии с рекомендациями, использовать Streaming.